# Why Loken did not confront Mournival about Erebus treachery?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

In the book "False Gods" (second book of "Horus Heresy" series), there is a situation where Loken realises that Erebus have stolen the anathema in order to later indirectly poison the Warmaster. At the time this happens, Horus is already almost dead and locked in the temple on Davin.

After that, Loken lands on a planet to find his Mournival brothers standing in front of the entrance to the temple. But instead of giving his brothers detailed account of what happened he just kind of...exchanges a couple of words with them and leaves?

Why Loken did not tell his brothers in as much detail as possible what he already knows in order to explain why this whole thing needs to stop? Sure, Abaddon was already quite angry at him because of the Karkassy exchange, but he could at least persuade Aximand and other brothers.

I would be very grateful if somebody could point me to what I am missing here. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Because he didn't understand the nature of the treachery

Please remember, that this is still the time of the Imperial Truth, according to which there are no gods, no Chaos, only pure science.

Yes, Loken has found out that Erebus has stolen the Anatheme blade, but for him, this was just that- a blade. Maybe a powerful and poisonous, bot nothing else.

> What I can't figure out is why? Why go to all the trouble of stealing this thing and then bringing it here?'
>
> 'I'm going to break that son of a bitch in two if he had something to do with what's happened to the Warmaster,’ snarled Torgaddon. 'The Legion will have his hide,’
>
> **'No,’ hissed Loken, 'not yet. Not until we find out what this is all about and if anyone else is involved. . I just can't believe that someone would dare try and move against the Warmaster,’**
>
> Is that what you think is happening, a coup? You think that one of the other primarchs is making a play for the role of Warmaster?'

> 'I don't know, it all sounds too far fetched.

So Loken knows that Erebus is somehow involved in wounding Horus, but he doesn't understand why Chaplain would do such thing:

> Loken tried to collect his thoughts [...]
> He might have been able to believe that, but for the presence of the anathame and his certainty that First Chaplain Erebus had lied to him on the voyage to Davin.
> Karkasy had said that Erebus wanted Horas to come to Davin's moon, and his undoubted
> complicity- in the theft of the anathame could **lead to only one conclusion. Erebus had wanted  Horus to be killed here. That didn't make any sense either.** Why go to such convoluted lengths just to kill the Warmaster, surely there had to be more to it than that... Whatever was going on, he would uncover the conspiracy and make those involved pay with their lives.

ESPECIALLY, since it seems that Erebus is trying to save Horus life:

> 'What have you done?' he asked. 'Oh my brothers, what have you done?'
>
> 'What needed to be done,' said Abaddon, when Aximand didn't answer. [...]
> '**It is as Ezekyle said. We did what had to be done,’ said Aximand. 'The Warmaster was dying and Vaddon couldn't save him. So we brought him to the Delphos.'**

It all doesn't make sense to him, even if he is very suspicious of this:

> 'How did you even think to bring him here anyway? Was it some secret knowledge your damned lodge is privy to?' None of his brothers spoke, and as Loken searched their faces for answers, **the truth of the matter was suddenly, horribly, clear to him. 'Erebus told you of this place, didn't he?'**
>
> 'Yes,’ admitted Targost. 'He knows of these lodges of old and has seen the power of their healing houses. If the Warmaster lives you will be thankful he spoke of it,’
>
> **'I believe you have all been deceived, my brothers,’ said Loken.** 'Only the Emperor has the power to heal the Warmaster now. All else is falsehood and the domain of unclean corpse whisperers,’
>
> The Emperor is not here,’ said Targost bluntly. We take what aid we can,’

The fact that he starts to argue with Abaddon and the rest of Morunivals doesn't help. He doesn't voice his suspicions because in the end they make no sense and, after all Horus is back alive, better than ever.